# Problems with making a right sidebar With Tailwind and React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Following is my website structure:

```html
    <div>
      <div>
        <Headline /> {/*A TopBar Serves As a HeadLine*/}
      </div>
      {/* Left Side Bar */}

      <div className="flex">
        <LeftSideBar CatalogueHandler={showCatalogueHandler} />
        
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <div>
            {showCatalogue ? <Catalogue /> : <></>}
            <div>
              heylo
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <Bottombar />
      </div>
      <RightBar/>
      <div>
      
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

This is my RightBar structure:

```js
import React from 'react' 
function RightBar() {
  return (
      <div className="fixed  h-screen bg-slate-200 top-0 right-0 w-24 right-0">
        Haylo
      </div>
  )
}
```

The following is my LeftSideBar structure (for reference):

```html
<div className="lg:flex flex-col items-center sticky top-0 w-24 h-screen bg-slate-200 hidden">
{/*Content Here*/}
</div>
```

My left bar is perfect. It respects the Headline component at the top and it's rendered just below it (exactly how I want it to), however my right-side bar is pushing the Headline component for the length of its own width to left as you can see, and it takes the Headline component's place.

[image: How my Website Currently Looks]

If I use top-8 Tailwind class it renders good initially, but since Headline is not a sticky component, when I scroll it remain at the top and my right bar has this white space at the top when I scroll.

Comment: changing the right bar to position sticky doesn't fix it?

Comment: @Quak_2023 RightBar is Also Fixed, adding sticky won't do it, I've tried it.

Comment: and If I add a div that wraps the current rightside bar, and give it a className="sticky", it ends up giving the same result as above

Comment: im saying right sidebar shound "Not" be fixed instead it should be sticky also you should prob move it into the same div as the left bar. if you add a codesandbox id be happy to try to fix it for you

Comment: @Quak_2023 thanks alot brother, I just fixed it, I used different strategy